# image doesn't displayed on other pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr9X2.png)- I have more than the HOME PAGE and for some reason, the logo picture does not appear on the other pages. Do you have any idea how to fix that?
[sample page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6wTS.png)

whenever i try to fix for another page the previous one gives the same problem.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">

Hello from header.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the browser isn't displaying the image because the browser can't find it using the instructions you gave it. Those instructions are the src attribute of the img tag...

Now, there are a few possible reasons why the browser cannot find the image. You might have one problem going on, or all of them. Let's go through the following exercises to see if maybe we can narrow down the problem.

First, try putting the image in the same folder as your HTML document
his is the simplest way to insert an image. As long as everything is in the same folder, things are pretty simple to find.

Possible snags?

Simple (but common) typo: scr= instead of src=
Mispelling the image name: src="mypick.gif" or src="my pic.gif" instead of src="mypic.gif"
Wrong extension: src="mypic.jpg" when your image is a gif... mypic.gif. (Should I use gif or jpg? You might find this interesting.)
Malformed img tag...

Before going on to other possible reasons for your missing image, make sure that you can successfully insert an image as shown above.